# LESS: Can't compile to css due to mysterious errors

Tags: compilation, less

I have a website developed in LESS CSS, with many .less files, some loaded directly from HEAD of page, others imported inside a parent one.

If I load website using JS on-the-fly compiler, no problem at all, everything runs correctly.

If I try to compile them in CSS (I tried with SimpLESS importing the entire project folder), it give me some errors:

- Missing files (is impossible because, as I said, website runs correctly)
- Error at specific line in one of them (again, an "error" that with JS compiling, runs correctly)
- etc...

How can I compile my LESS???

Please, consider that I don't need to compile every time I make an edit, but only once, just before uploading my website on webserver, so.... manually, is perfect.

Comment: P.S.: Please, note that even if I have a webserver base on LAMP, locally I am in a Windows environment.

Comment: It is quite possible that it is a difference in LESS version that is the problem. LESS is at 1.7 as of right now, but looking at the change log, [SimpLESS is only using version 1.3](http://wearekiss.com/simpless). There was a lot of changes from 1.7 to 1.3.

Comment: Ok, what do you suggest instead, assuming my needs? :-)

Comment: http://lesscss.org/usage/

Comment: I tried SimpLESS and WinLESS.... they don't do what I want and give me many errors in compiling suche as "variable not defined". File in which are declared variable is succesfully compiled but files use this variables and import the original files, give errors.

I want to emphasize that if I compile on-the-fly through LESS.js in abrowser, everything works correctly, so is not a problem of missing references..... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this command line compilr, [LESS.js for Windows](https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows) that correctly ad quickly converts my LESS files without errors.